# How do I set input type based on variable in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I set up an input type based on another variable? (My initial thought was to have) the directive trigger from the onclick event, which should set the input type. I thought about using a directive but not sure

**FIRST**

```
//loop
<a class="orgTitle" id="@c.Id" data-ng-click="selectQuestion(@c.Id, @c.SelectionTypeId);" style="cursor:pointer">@c.ProgramName</a>
```

**THEN**

```
$scope.selectQuestion = function(id, selectionTypeId) {//call returns data and push to QuestionList}
```

**FINALLY**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in angularPage.QuestionList">
<span>{{question.Question}}</span><br/>
<span>//directive to get my answer type, whether radiobutton or textbox</span>
```

Comment: You can't set/change input type dynamically. You need to use ng-switch or similar directive to render different input field depending on dynamic value.

Comment: IE doesn't allow it, so Angular succumbs to it in order to stay cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @MrM if I get it right in your case the type will not be change dynamically. `ng-repeat` on its own recreates DOM structure when changes happen.

Comment: so would I be able to create an input element with ng-repeat at least? @arturgrzesiak

Comment: @MrM did you try to implement my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing a directive like this:
Pseudo-Code, **this was not tested!**

```
angular.module('inputType', [])
  .directive('inputType', function (/**injects here*/) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        var inputType = scope.$eval(attr.inputType);
        element.attr('type', inputType);
      }
  })
});
```

Then in html:

```
<input input-type="myDynamicInputType" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I... I mean, we figured it out! Because jquery restricts the type property change, I did an append on the html input type.

**HTML**

```
<input-type question-type="question.myDynamicInputType" />
```

**js**

```
.directive('inputType', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $(element).append('<input type="' + scope.$eval(attr.inputType) + '" />');
        }
    }
});
```

**element**

```
<input-type question-type="question.myDynamicInputType">
    <input type="number">
</input-type>
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: if some answer helped you, please mark it as answered. People are looking for the green checkmark ;)